# Unable to use "Create new XXX"

Tags: oracle-apex

When I try to create a region, either by clicking the + next to Regions, or by right-clicking on `Regions>Content Body>"Create Region"`, APEX just creates a region with static content. It does NOT present the create region wizard.
Why is this?
A basic question, hopefully someone can help me here.
Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow please take a minute to read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The same think happens with buttons, etc. I just get a default XXX created, then I have to go to change all the defaults in the right-hand-side pane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Apex default region then you have to select what type of region you want. but if you want to create a specific region directly go to Layout ---> region ---> and choose the type of region you want.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neuXP.png)

for form region click to + button on the top of your page then chooose your type of form region you want 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urX1N.png)